# How to handle this DB schema?

Tags: database, database-design

Using SO as a prime example, let's say a `question` or `answer` to a question is deleted but garnered a few up-votes before it was deleted. I imagine these points are still awarded to the author (if they aren't, let's suppose they are), then how does SO keep an *accurate* reputation total?

Are the questions/answers actually *not* deleted from the DB itself, and perhaps have a status field that is processed and decides whether a question or answer is visible?

Or, they are, in fact, deleted and the reputation relies on the system being continuously accurate as each vote is counted and doesn't necessarily have a history of it (like a question that recorded the vote)

Comment: No idea how SO works but the last two options you've mentioned are the apparent ways. I guess which is best depends on if you ever want to be able to entirely delete a question to reduce data in the database. Plus there is also the performance issue of having to look up all previous Q/As to sum the total, so I'm guessing they'd do the latter.

Comment: This isn't really a clear question.

Comment: @regulatethis What would you like me to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO uses a combination of soft and hard deletes, to the best of my knowledge.  I can say for sure that I've lost reputation that was gained on questions deleted by either the poster or the moderator.  That is not the point of your question, however, so...

If you want to be able to deduce an accurate total, especially if you want to be able to account for that total (the way SO lets you do by looking at your points history) then you need to keep **transactional information**, not a running total.

If you want to have referential integrity for the transactional log of points then you will need to use a soft-delete mechanism to hide questions that are "deleted".

If you don't keep the transactional log and you don't have soft delete-able questions to back up your transactional points log, then you won't be able to either recalculate or justify point totals.  You'll also have a much harder time displaying a graph of points awarded over time and accumulated reputation over time.  You could do these graphs by keeping a daily point snapshot, but that would be much more onerous and costly in terms of storage than just tracking up and down votes.

Comment: I planned on keeping the transactional information, *and* keep a field with a running total. This should maintain referential integrity, and wouldn't require re-calculating the reputation on each page load for each person. Is this acceptable? Drawbacks? If so, when should a person's reputation get re-evaluated? Is this pre-optimization unnecessary?

Comment: @Josh I generally recommend against preoptimization.  If your load testing or production experience dictates that you need to keep a denormalized running total then go ahead and do that.  However, you have to be prepared to have an argument with your users about discrepancies that will inevitably creep in between the transactional details and the calculated running total.  If it were me, and if I found the preoptimization necessary, then I suppose I would recalculate every time a new transaction was added.  This presumably saves you calculating on reads, just on writes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Joel. Like you said, I'll save on calculating on the reads with the running total, and will maintain the transaction information for future uses.